# $A^k=A$ is diagonalizable over field of order $k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a square matrix over a field $F$ of order $k$ such that $A^k=A$. Is it true that $A$ is diagonalizable over $F$?

I think it’s true since the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $F$ are products of some factors of $x^k-x$. So the minimal polynomial of $A$ over $F$ is a product of distinct linear polynomials hence $A$ is diagonalizable. However I cannot find any sources about this so I just wanted to verify. Thank you.

Comment: Yours is a correct argument.

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2019566/11619).

Comment: Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "I think it’s true since the minimal polynomial of A over F are products of some factors of xk−x. So the minimal polynomial of A over F is a product of distinct linear polynomials hence A is diagonalizable. However I cannot find any sources about this so I just wanted to verify. Thank you."

**Question 2:** "I'm trying to prove that if a linear operator f is diagonalisable then its minimal polynomial is the product of distinct linear factors."

**Remark:** If we define an $n \times n$-matrix $A \in M(n\times n,k):=R$ with coefficients in a field $k$ to be diagonalizable iff there is an invertible matrix $P\in R$ with $P^{-1}AP =D$ with $D$ a diagonal matrix, it follows the zero matrix $D(0)$ (the matrix with zeros as coefficients) is a diagonalizable matrix. For any invertible matrix $P$ it follows

$$D(0)=P^{-1}D(0)P.$$

The matrix $D(0)$ has all eigenvalues equal to zero. By definition: The minimal polynomial $f(t)$ of $D(0)$ is the unique monic polynomial generating the ideal $I$ with

$$I:=\{f(t) \in k[t]: f(D(0))=0 \}$$

and $I=(t)$ has $f(t):=t$ as unique monic generator. And this polynomial
has one linear factor.