# If minimal polynomial of a matrix A is irreducible, is A diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Given A is a $7\times7$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $ (\lambda -3)^5 (\lambda-1)^2$ and if minimal polynomial of A is irreducible, is A diagonalizable?

My attempt: I am not sure of what would be the possibilities for minimal polynomial to be irreducible.  If minimal polynomial is $(\lambda-1)$ or $(\lambda-3)$, then it would be irreducible, but then minimal polynomial should contain all eigen values making
$(\lambda-1) (\lambda-3)$ as the only possibility.  Please suggest.

Comment: You are right. The minimal polynomial must be divisible by $(\lambda-3)(\lambda-1)$ and hence it cannot possibly be irreducible. The question assigned to you probably has some typos.

Comment: I think that's badly posed question. The condition equivalent to diagonalization is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2014324/if-f-is-diagonalisable-then-its-minimal-polynomial-is-the-product-of-distinct), indeed satisfied by your $A$